# Авторизация Vk, access Token

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток[image: введите сюда описание изображения] хочу получить доступ к методам VK Api. Объясните пожалуйста, почему:

1. В документации сказано, что в методе responseType должен быть указан параметр "code", чтобы в дальнейшем получить токен доступа. Но я могу его получить написав responseType("token"), зачем этот "code"?
2. Почему-то "code", который приведен в документации отличается от моего, как будто часть моего "code" обрезана.

   ```
   public static void main(String... args) {
       final String clientId = "5811559"; // ID моего приложения Vk
       final String clientSecret = "ZOAAWpmdT6h4AGkSGGYV"; //Секретный ключ
       final OAuth20Service service = new ServiceBuilder()
                   .apiKey(clientId)
                   .apiSecret(clientSecret)
                   .callback("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html ")
                   .scope("friends")
                   .responseType("code")
                   .build(VkontakteApi.instance());
   }
   ```

Должно получиться что-то такое:

```
REDIRECT_URI?code=7a6fa4dff77a228eeda56603b8f53806c883f011c40b72630bb50df056f6479e52a
```

А выходит:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#code=6b42804b417113a2af
```

Comment: надеюсь указанные clientId и clientSecret не настоящие? иначе вы только, что отдали секретную информацию всему интернету.

Comment: если это реальные данные, то обязательно поменяйте их.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, на stackoverflow можно смотреть историю изменений :-)

Comment: Поэтому надо менять не тут, а в VK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кратко.. VK OAuth API поддерживают 3 метода, первый и самый простой вы можете использовать одноэтапную авторизацию, т.е сразу в первом запросе вызвать значение TOKEN и продолжить получение данных. Есть и двухэтапная авторизация, при котором вы сначала получаете значение CODE после отправляете ещё один запрос для получения TOKEN по данному коду... всё зависит от того  что вам нужно и как вы реализуете ваш проект.
Что касается длины значения CODE, насколько помню таких коротких не должно быть, но вы можете отправить запрос на получения access_token и если CODE неправильный, то вам система ответит ошибкой что ваш CODE не верный..
P.S. старайтесь данные о своём application (clientId,clientSecret ) не писать публично! это секретная инфа ))

Comment: Ну не сказал бы, что Client ID (ID приложения) такой уж и секретный.